# How to get the proportions of data with respect to two variables in R?

Tags: r

I have 4 columns: Vehicle ID, Vehicle Class, Vehicle Length and Vehicle Width. Every vehicle has a unique vehicle ID (e.g. 2, 4, 5,...) and the data was collected every 0.1 seconds which means that vehicle IDs are repeated in Vehicle ID column for the number of times they were observed. There are three vehicle classes i.e. 1=motorcycles, 2=cars, 3=trucks in the Vehicle Class column and the lengths and widths are in their respective columns against every vehicle ID. I want to subset the data by vehicle class and then find the proportions of each vehicle model (unique length and width) within every class. For example, for the Vehicle Class = 2 i.e. car, I want to find different models of cars (unique length and width) and their proportions with respect to total number of cars. Here is what I have done so far:

## To subset data by Vehicle Class

```
cars <- subset(b, b$'Vehicle class'==2)
trucks <- subset(b, b$'Vehicle class'==3)
motorcycles <- subset(b, b$'Vehicle class'==1)
```

## To find the number of cars

```
numofcars <- length(unique(cars$'Vehicle ID')) # 2830
numoftrucks <- length(unique(trucks$'Vehicle ID')) # 137
numofmotorcycles <- length(unique(motorcycles$'Vehicle ID'))# 45
```

The above code worked but I could not find the proportions by using the code below:

```
by (cars, INDICES=cars$'Vehicle Length', FUN=table(cars$'Vehicle width'))
```

R gives an error stating that it could not find 'FUN'. Please help me in finding the proportions of each model within all classes of vehicles.

## EDIT (Sample Input)

```
Vehicle ID Vehicle Class Vehicle Length Vehicle Width
2 2 13.5 4.5
2 2 13.5 4.5
2 2 13.5 4.5
2 2 13.5 4.5
3 2 13.5 4.0
3 2 13.5 4.0
3 2 13.5 4.0
3 2 13.5 4.0
4 2 10.0 4.5
4 2 10.0 4.5
4 2 10.0 4.5
4 2 10.0 4.5
5 3 23.0 4.5
5 3 23.0 4.5
5 3 23.0 4.5
5 3 23.0 4.5
6 3 76.5 4.5
6 3 76.5 4.5
6 3 76.5 4.5
6 3 76.5 4.5
6 3 76.5 4.5
7 1 10.0 3.0
7 1 10.0 3.0
7 1 10.0 3.0
7 1 10.0 3.0
8 2 13.5 5.5
8 2 13.5 5.5
8 2 13.5 5.5
8 2 13.5 5.5
```

Note that in this input: Total number of cars=4, trucks=2, motorcycles=1

## Sample Output

```
Group: cars
VehicleLength VehicleWidth Proportion
13.5 4.5 0.25
13.5 4.0 0.25
13.5 5.5 0.25
23.0 4.5 0.25

Group:trucks
VehicleLength VehicleWidth Proportion
23.0 4.5 0.5
76.0 4.5 0.5

Group: motorcycles
VehicleLength VehicleWidth Proportion
10.0 3.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have given sample output and sample input to make it easier to answer. From what I understand, you want something along the lines of this -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt2 <- dt[,
          list(ClassLengthWidthFreq = .N), 
          by = c('VehicleClass','VehicleLength','VehicleWidth')
          ]
dt2[,
    ClassLengthWidthFreqProportion := ClassLengthWidthFreq / sum(ClassLengthWidthFreq), 
    by = 'VehicleClass'
    ]
```

Output -

```
> dt2
   VehicleClass VehicleLength VehicleWidth ClassLengthWidthFreq ClassLengthWidthFreqProportion
1:            2          13.5          4.5                    4                      0.2500000
2:            2          13.5          4.0                    4                      0.2500000
3:            2          10.0          4.5                    4                      0.2500000
4:            3          23.0          4.5                    4                      0.4444444
5:            3          76.5          4.5                    5                      0.5555556
6:            1          10.0          3.0                    4                      1.0000000
7:            2          13.5          5.5                    4                      0.2500000
```

If not, then please add sample output and sample input.

Comment: I have added the sample input and output

Comment: This solution works then. Instead of three tables, it returns one table with `Vehicleclass` as one of the columns. You can subset on `dt2` as you've shown in your question to get three separate datasets if you'd like, although I don't see why it can't just be one dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works. The only problem is that it is not giving correct 'ClassLengthWidthFreq'. It reports the frequency much higher than expected e.g. the first value it reports is 18677 (when applied to original data). This might be because it is counting the repetitions of the same vehicle also when it should count it only once.

Comment: I just posted my output, it matches your sample output (except your trucks frequency is calculated incorrectly in your sample output). I don't understand the problem you've mentioned in your comment.

Comment: What I was mentioning is that in my Original Data when I used your code, the output frequency was 18677 which means 18677 cars having length=13.5 and width=4.5. This is not correct because I know that total number of cars are 2830. I think the reason for such large output is that instead of correctly counting the repetition of same vehicle over time as 1 for a given model, it counts same model again the number of times it is found in table.

Comment: That is something you should have made clear in the sample input and output. I don't see a time column in your data, why don't you reset `df <- unique(df)` in that case and try again.

Comment: In your output the frequency is taking into account the number of repetitions, which is not required because model is same, it is only repeated because the data was recorded over 45 minute time period with observations every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to measure the length and width of the car over multiple time periods if they aren't changing. Anyway, the `unique` statement I proposed in the previous comment should fix it.